# Angular ng-controller does not show output

Tags: angularjs

I start AngularJs, the out is not shown when i write something in js file.

```
html ng-app

  script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-rc.3/angular.min.js"

body ng-controller="simpleController"
    <br />
    {{tags}}

function simpleController($scope){

  $scope.tags = [

    {done: false, text: 'fist'}

  ];
}

{{tags}} is not updating when i make some change.
```

Comment: no explanation what so ever, just code -1. please explain to us what you are looking for in the question. Take more time and care with your questions they should be there to help everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer following working code -

```js
function simpleController($scope) {
    $scope.tags = [

    {
        done: false,
        text: 'fist'
    }

    ];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app>
    
    <body ng-controller="simpleController">{{tags}}</body>

</html>
```